# How do I resolve error 2035 with the Adobe Flash Debugger?

Tags: flash

I've been working on downloading some swf games so that I can play them by myself after flash is discontinued.
I downloaded a couple of nostalgic ones that were practically abandonware, virus scanned them, and loaded them into Adobe's Standalone Player, the flash debugger.

However, I keep getting the `error code 2035`, and it says "`url not found.`"  Then, it just stays on the loading screen forever.
My guess is that the swf files have scripts in them that reach out to grab assets from its original server (a server that is still online and running, thankfully.)
Because the swf file was copied to my computer's local environment, it may not be able to locate the assets it needs to function.
The game itself should be capable of functioning offline with some modifications, because the games I've downloaded only really need the server for assets (apparently), and a soon to be defunct points system that awards kids, although the games I grabbed award no points.

Is there a way I can inspect a website's element, find the assets the swf needs and retrieve them?
The way things are going, it seems like these two specific games may not be archived by anyone and I'm worried they may be lost to time and I'll never be able to play again.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In **Google Chrome** you can open the web console that shows all the **HTTP** requests and answers. Use it to learn which assets this application (while functioning normally) requests to download them as well. If your case is simple, it will be enough to get a working local copy.

Comment: @Organis Thank you for your help!  I opened the console, and aside from sponsor and ad requests which didn't pertain to the game I tried this out with, and it displayed a list of links that I think I might need.  I would ask you to look at it, but I'm not sure how to paste code blocks because I am new...  Is there a way to do that when responding to people?  I've seen other users do it before.

Comment: Use [edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65521604/edit) to add extra info. There is a `code` button in the editor so just select your code text and press it.